# GridView is not smooth. How to optimize the grideview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have created simple image gallery which displays images stored in `res/drawable` folder , but the grid view is very laggy and slow. How can I optimized the gridview further more so that the movement is smooth.

```
  public class ImageGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    String strCategoryName = null;
    GridView gridView;
    Utils utils;
    private int columnWidth;

    // private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        Intent intent;
        intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            strCategoryName = intent.getStringExtra("category");
        }


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_cards);
        utils = new Utils(this);

        // Intializing Grid View
        InitilizeGridLayout();
        // gridView.setAdapter(new GridCustomAdapter(this));

        // adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(ImageGalleryActivity.this,
        // defaultImages, columnWidth, this);

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        if(strCategoryName.equals("test"))
        {
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i1));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i2));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i3));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i4));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i5));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i6));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i7));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i8));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i9));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i10));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i11));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i12));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i13));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i14));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i15));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i16));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i17));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i18));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i19));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i20));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i21));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i22));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i23));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i24));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i25));
        }
        else if(strCategoryName.equals("test")){
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i1));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i2));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i3));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i4));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i5));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i6));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i7));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i8));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i9));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i10));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i11));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i12));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i13));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i14));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i15));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i16));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i17));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i18));

        }else{
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i1));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i2));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i3));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i4));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i5));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i6));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i7));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i8));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i9));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i10));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i11));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i12));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i13));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i14));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i15));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i16));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i17));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.i18));
        }



        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, items, columnWidth, ImageGalleryActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void InitilizeGridLayout() {

        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
                (int) padding);

        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
    }

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Item> items;
    private Context context;
    int columnWidth;
    Activity _activity;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items, int columnWidth, Activity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
        this._activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.frame_layout_square_image_view, null, false);

            holder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.picture.setImageBitmap((decodeImage(
                items.get(position).drawableId, columnWidth)));
         holder.picture.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(items.get(position).drawableId));
        return convertView;
    }
    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        int _drawableId;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int drawableId) {
            this._drawableId = drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_activity, ImageEditor.class);
            i.putExtra("drawableId", _drawableId);
            _activity.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    class ViewHolder {

        ImageView picture;

    }

    public Bitmap decodeImage(int resourceId, int imageSize) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = imageSize; // you are free to modify size
                                                    // as your requirement

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    resourceId, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}

class Item {

    final int drawableId;

    Item(int drawableId) {
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try using Picasso or ImageLoader to load your images into imageViews instead of setImageBitmap. These 2 options will load images in background and cache them in memory, and your option is loading images into views constantly while you scroll

Comment: @MateKrižanac: How to use Picasso or ImageLoaded using the images given from the res/drawable folder

Answer (score 2):

Try gridView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true); it will use a more refined calculation method based on the pixels height of the items visible on screen. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html
Hope this may help.

Comment: worked little smooth then before, but still not so smooth as I want.

Answer (score 0):

First I think that this line:

```
holder.picture.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(items.get(position).drawableId));
```

is quite heavy, you allocate an anonymous class at each getView call. If you really want to be sure you can track your memory allocation (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc).

What you could easily do is a listener member that you allocate only once :

```
private OnClickListener myImageClickListener = new OnImageClickListener();
```

And then in your getView you just

```
holder.picture.setOnClickListener(myImageClickListener);
```

To have a more "generic" listener you could (in your getView):

```
holder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
holder.picture.setTag(items.get(position).drawableId);
```

And then:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int drawableId = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag());
}
```

That might already ease the pain :)

Comment: But then I am passing an int argument with the anonymous class. How cab that be achieved using the code you have given.

Comment: I edited my answer to handle your drawableId. By doing this you remove the need to have the argument in your anonymous class. Tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you with a very unsmooth scrolling experience. I agree with Mate Krizanac - basically what you want to do is do any image loading on a thread that isn't the main UI thread. So you could use Picasso or ImageLoader class, or alternatively use a AsyncTask to load the image into your ViewHolder. Another way to optimize would be to scale the images down a bit. There is plenty of code online that can help you with that. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need actual code to explain.